# Training on dataset with incomplete labels

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, resnet

I have a problem where I have about 10k labeled images for semantic segmentation. These have been labeled with 8 different class labels.

For about 4k of them I have extra labels for a different (but very similar problem). I am able to transform these labels to fit into the original problem thereby extending the 8 classes to 9. Now I wish to train on these 9 classes without wasting the 6k classes that are missing these extra class labels.

The plan was as so

1. Train 6k set for 8 classes
2. Initialize new network for 9 classes with weights loaded from (1)
3. Freeze all but score layer and retrain on 4k set
4. Train 4k set again but with weights loaded from (3)

I have done this and have tried multiple things with step(4). I have frozen stages progressively (Resnet50) and have tried lowering the learning rate. None have reached similar performance. I expect a small drop due to the added complexity but the problems are very similar where one class was split in two. I would expect some confusion between these two classes but all other classes are failing to perform as well.

Whats the correct way to extend the problem to added an extra class label where not all of the dataset contains this extra label.